# Including a php file with includes into a smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

I want to include my header into a script that uses **smarty templates**.  From searching this site, I am partially there, but not quite:

```
{include file='/home/username/public_html/header.php'}
```

This successfully includes the image in the header, but neither of two includes the header contains.  One of the includes is a php file, and the other is html (my bootstrap nav bar). I seems from my searches that I need to make a plugin, which according to one post is "easy", but I can't find an example of how to accomplish this?

---

based on codefreaks inststructions, here's what I did. I'm sure the instructions are correct, I'm just not interpreting them correctly, as this isn't displaying anything.

Here are the three files, with their paths in relation to the public_html directory, and what I added to them.  Everything is exactly as I put it: no words here are placeholders.

**file 1**
    `sitewide/myheader.php`

```
<?
ob_start(); 
--- I didn't change the original content here --
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();  ?>
```

**File 2**
    `newscript/includes/page_header.php`

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
require "/home/username/public_html/sitewide/myheader.php";
$smarty->assign('myheader', $output);
$smarty->display('../themes/default/template/header.tpl');
```

**File 3**
    `newscript/themes/default/template/header.tpl`

```
{$myheader}
```

Comment: You should not include raw PHP files into your smarty templates. Only include smarty templates into smarty templates. Smarty does only presentation logic and so it should deal with presentation logic files, which are in your case templates written with smarty. Also, try using relative paths (those without beginning slashes). If they are in the same directory, just type in their names.

Comment: This script is just one part of my website, and is the only part that uses smarty, so I know nothing about it.  I have a header file that is used throughout my site, that I edit once, and all pages see the changes.  I changed the paths to relative as you suggested, but no changes.

How do I turn my header file into a smarty template?  Does this mean every time I edit my header I'll have to edit the new smarty template as well?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can include your php file in smarty.

As samrty is a template engine,

PHP pages executes first, then it sends the data to your smarty page.

Solution : Pass all data needed from php  page to smarty, and include html page, with smarty variables.

Comment: thanks codefreak - didn't have to find a bridge after all.  Since my site isn't based on Smarty, just that one script, I had to modify your suggestion a bit, but your example helped me understand the smarty concepts enough to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

After getting feedback from you and testing myself, I figured out you might not have set up smarty properly. Follow instructions at http://www.smarty.net/quick_install to install it properly. My final directory structure after setting up properly looks like:

[image]

Once you have it set it up properly this is code I used in files:

index.php

```
<?php
echo "hello";
require_once "libs/Smarty.class.php";
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->setTemplateDir('smarty/templates');
$smarty->setCompileDir('smarty/templates_c');
$smarty->setCacheDir('smarty/cache');
$smarty->setConfigDir('smarty/configs');
require "header.php";

$smarty->assign('header', $output);
$smarty->testInstall();
$smarty->display('smarty.tpl');
echo "hello";
?>
```

header.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
hello honey bunny
<?php
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Put smarty.tpl in templates folder!

```
{$header}hellos
```

Comment: codefreak said "It's better to grab output of header.php in a variable and pass it on to smarty template."  Sounds great.  How?  Remember I'm clueless about Smarty.

Comment: man u must be tired! :P I think i have to open editor and write code and test it for you... give me few minutes I will get back to u

Comment: I once again edited the answer.. if it still doesn't work, go jump off a bridge I have nothing more to say :)

Comment: ok... I see what happens.  It will either work, or I'll go choose a bridge!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do a very similar thing except all I want is some global PHP constants that I have defined in a stand alone **constants.php** file using **define**.

I want those same said constants in my smarty templates so I've been trying to include **constants.php** in the smarty template but this is better a better way to do this:

In **constants.php**

```
  $_CONSTANT['TBL']                      = TRUE;  
  $_CONSTANT['FLD']                      = FALSE;
  $_CONSTANT['DB_READ_SUCCESS']          =     1;
  $_CONSTANT['DB_WRITE_SUCCESS']         =     1;
  $_CONSTANT['DB_WRITE_ERROR_UNKNOWN']   =  -100;    

  //*** Copy the $_CONSTANT array to PHP define() to make global PHP constants
  foreach($_CONSTANT as $key => $value) {
    define($key, $value);
  }
```

Then in my smarty set up function I do this:

```
foreach ($_CONSTANT as $key => $value) {
  Smarty->assign($key, $value);
}
```

And really I think variable (or constant) values is all you really want in your Smarty templates to keep your view layer separate from your model and controller layers.

**Post Script:**

In fact you can use this technique to pass your PHP constants, using Smarty, to JavaScript allowing you to declare you constants in one place for three different environments: PHP, Smarty, and JavaScript.

Here's how:

**Call the following from your smarty set up function:**

```
  public function AssignJSConstants($values) {
    $js = '';
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
      if ($key != 'CR') {
        if (is_string($value)) {
          $js = $js.$key.' = "'.$value.'";';
        } else {
          $js = $js.$key.' = '.$value.';';
        }
        $js = $js.CR.'      ';
      }
    }
    $this->Smarty->assign('JavaScriptConstants', $js);
  }
```

**And then declare the following in your smarty template:**

```
<script>
  //php constants that exported to JavaScript
  {$JavaScriptConstants}
</script>
```

**Which will give you this in your HTML:**

```
<script>
  //php constants that exported to JavaScript
  TBL = 1;
  FLD = 0;
  DB_READ_SUCCESS = 1;
  DB_READ_ERROR_UNKNOWN = -10;
  DB_WRITE_SUCCESS = 1;
  DB_WRITE_ERROR_UNKNOWN = -100;
</script>
```

Comment: Don't forget, as I did, to declare **$_CONSTANT** as global in the smarty setup function: